# implementing an editor in java linked to the gui

Tags: java, editor

is there any editor in Java?  To expand that, want to - let's say - open a text file, edit it, and then save it back or cancel?

What I want to do is that I have a GUI and I want to click a button that will bring up the file chooser, then I choose my text file that will be opened using this editor, I will then edit the file and finally save it or cancel to not save the changes, which will return me back to my GUI.

I would like to do all of these while in the Java environment, closing the GUI, editing the file and then reopening can be easily done.

Comment: Are you trying to make a program like notepad??

Comment: yes in a way, i would like to attach this "notepad" to my UI, and be able to edit my text files on the go.

Comment: well i would prefer if i found the program ready , im coding a game which two players enter their text files of the strategy they want to use. They can alter this strategy with a sandbox thing that will allow them to edit their strategy on the run , and then test it on the system on the go without having to go about and alter the text file themselves through the file path system.

Comment: You will have to code it yourself

Comment: @Martinos:  "hello there, is there any editor in java?"  I don't know.  But if you manage to code one, could you add some checks for typing in all lower case that pop a dialog telling the user that their words are more likely to be read if they take the (immense) effort to use their shift key at the start of sentences & for words like 'I' & 'Java'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are Trying to make your own editor, Its a big process. You got to construct your UI, (1 big text area) set up a file chooser.

Basically use a `JFrame` with a `JTextArea` `JFileChooser`

Comment: i would really prefer if there is a ready made text editor that i can use

Comment: Im sorry i cannot help you with that, you wll need to find an open source 1 that you can use.

Comment: @Martinos You question mentioned implementing one so RMT's answer is technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that exactly what you are asking for, but sure enough there's [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), which is an editor written in Java.

Comment: i would really prefer if there is a ready made text editor that i can use

Comment: I think he wants to intergrate it with his program he already made

Answer (score 0):

> that will allow them to edit their strategy on the run

I don't know much about games, but why would the "strategy" be expressed in a text file? I would think you would want to use check boxes or radio buttons or combo boxes to allow the user to alter the strategy by selecting keywords etc. Then your could store the strategy is a Properties file.

A text editor would not allow for editing of the text for valid values or key works. So if the user entered "abcd" I'm sure that would be just garbage. If all you want is text then a JTextArea should work just fine, since I don't see that you need any need for highlighting or bolding of the text. A text area supports the ability to read() and write() the contents from and to a file directly.

What are the exact feature you expect this "text editor" to provide?

Comment: just read and write basically to a text file, and save the changes